# Previous button and next button

Tags: java, android

I have <> and <> buttons in my quiz app, but if the user is in the first question since there is no previous question there should be toast which says "this is the first question" and the same with <>button.

Here is my code for buttons (which is incorrect):

```
 mNextButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.next_button);

    mNextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                mCurreentIndex=0;
                if (mCurreentIndex>mQuestionBank.length){
                    Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this,R.string.last_question,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            updateQuestion();
        }
    });

    mPreviousButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.previous_button);

    mPreviousButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mCurreentIndex--;
            if (mCurreentIndex<mQuestionBank.length){
                Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, R.string.first_question,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            updateQuestion();
        }
    });
```

Comment: how is your quiz questions designed? have you used a view pager? post your activity or fragment code

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout ...>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/question_text_view".../>
<LinearLayout<Button
      android:id="@+id/true_button"
      android:text="@string/true_button" ... /><Button
        android:id="@+id/false_button"
        android:text="@string/false_button".../>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout...>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/previous_button"
        android:text="@string/previous_button".../><Button
        android:id="@+id/next_button"
        android:text="@string/next_button".... />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

Answer (score 0):

//Previous Button Condition;

```
   mCurreentIndex--; 
if (mCurreentIndex<mQuestionBank.length && mCurreentIndex>=0){
                Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, R.string.first_question,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
else {
  Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "This is first question",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
mCurreentIndex++; 
}
```

//Next Button Condition;

```
 mCurreentIndex++;
                if (mCurreentIndex<mQuestionBank.length){
                    Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this,R.string.last_question,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

else {
  Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "This is last Question",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
mCurreentIndex--;
}
```

Comment: Check this, I have rewrite these.

Answer (score 0):

```
mNextButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.next_button);

 mNextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
             //mCurreentIndex=0;// not valid
             if (mCurreentIndex>=mQuestionBank.length){
                 Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this,getString(R.string.last_question),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
             }
        mCurreentIndex++;
         updateQuestion();
     }
 });

 mPreviousButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.previous_button);

 mPreviousButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {

         if (mCurreentIndex<=0){
             Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, getString(R.string.first_question),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
         }
        mCurreentIndex--;
         updateQuestion();
     }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
mPreviousButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mCurreentIndex<=0){
                Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, R.string.first_question,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else{
                mCurreentIndex--;
                updateQuestion();
            }
        }
    });



 mNextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
         if (mCurreentIndex>=mQuestionBank.length){

             Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this,getString(R.string.last_question),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

         }else{
             mCurreentIndex++;
             updateQuestion();
        }

 }
```

});

Answer (score 0):

You have just display toast message but next statement also execute after displaying toast. For your solution you need to use "**return**" or **if..else** block.

```
     mNextButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.next_button);

        mNextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    mCurreentIndex=0;
                    if (mCurreentIndex>mQuestionBank.length){
                        Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this,R.string.last_question,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        return;
                    }
                updateQuestion();
            }
        });

        mPreviousButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.previous_button);

        mPreviousButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mCurreentIndex--;
                if (mCurreentIndex<mQuestionBank.length){
                    Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, R.string.first_question,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                }

                updateQuestion();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

public class QuizActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private static final String TAG = "QuizActivity";
private static final String KEY_INDEX = "index";

private Button mTrueButton;
private Button mFalseButton;
private Button mNextButton;
private Button mPreviousButton;
private TextView mQuestionTextView;

private Question[] mQuestionBank = new Question[]{
        new Question(R.string.question_australia, true),
        new Question(R.string.question_oceans, true),
        new Question(R.string.question_mideast, false),
        new Question(R.string.question_africa, false),
        new Question(R.string.question_americas, true),
        new Question(R.string.question_asia, true),
};

private int mCurreentIndex = 0;

private boolean[] QuestionsAnswered = new boolean[mQuestionBank.length];

@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d(TAG,"onCreate(Bundle) called");
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
     mCurreentIndex =savedInstanceState.getInt(KEY_INDEX, 0);
     QuestionsAnswered = savedInstanceState.getBooleanArray(KEY_INDEX);
    }

    mQuestionTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.question_text_view);



mTrueButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.true_button);
    mTrueButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           checkAnswer(true);
        }
    });


    mFalseButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.false_button);

    mFalseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          checkAnswer(false);
        }
    });

    mNextButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.next_button);

    mNextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mCurreentIndex = (mCurreentIndex+mQuestionBank.length +1) % mQuestionBank.length;
            updateQuestion();
        }
    });

    mPreviousButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.previous_button);

    mPreviousButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mCurreentIndex= (mCurreentIndex+ mQuestionBank.length - 1) % mQuestionBank.length;
            updateQuestion();
        }
    });
```

updateQuestion();
    }

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Log.d(TAG, "onStart() called");
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.d(TAG, "onResume() called");
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Log.d(TAG, "onPause() called");
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    savedInstanceState.putInt(KEY_INDEX,mCurreentIndex);
    savedInstanceState.putBooleanArray(KEY_INDEX,QuestionsAnswered);
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    Log.d(TAG, "onStop() called");
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy() called");
}

private void updateQuestion(){
    int question = mQuestionBank[mCurreentIndex].getTextResId();
    mQuestionTextView.setText(question);
    mTrueButton.setEnabled(!QuestionsAnswered[mCurreentIndex]);
    mFalseButton.setEnabled(!QuestionsAnswered[mCurreentIndex]);
}

private void checkAnswer(boolean userPressedTrue) {
    boolean answerIsTrue = mQuestionBank[mCurreentIndex].isAnswerTrue();
    int messageResId = 0;

    if (userPressedTrue == answerIsTrue) {
        messageResId = R.string.correct_toast;

    } else {
        messageResId = R.string.incorrect_toast;
    }
    Toast.makeText(this, messageResId, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    QuestionsAnswered[mCurreentIndex] = true;
    mTrueButton.setEnabled(false);
    mFalseButton.setEnabled(false);

}
```

}